# spring xd with rabbit errorQueue as errorChannel

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-xd

I have stream defined in my spring xd my stream looks something like this and transport is rabbit mq

```
stream source|transformer1|transformer2|transformer3|sink
```

I have custom transformers  which I have deployed.I want to  write all exception/error  happening in my transformers/custom modules to a errorQueue
I want to then pull the message in   errorQueue to mongoSink

I can achieve this by creating tap from rabbiterror queue to mongo

```
`tap -->rabbit_ERROR_QUEUE-->mongoSink`
```

Is there any way I  can configure my spring xd  custom modules xml to write all exception and error  to error queue by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `autoBindDLQ` to true (in `servers.yml` for all streams, or in the deployment properties at the stream level), XD will create a dead letter queue for you.

You also need to configure retry.

By default, the bus will try to deliver the message 3 times then reject it and the broker will forward it to the dead letter queue.

Another bus/deployment property `republishToDLQ` provides a mechanism for the bus to republish the message to the DLQ (instead of rejecting it). This will include additional information in the error message (exception exception etc) as headers.

See [the application configuration section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#application-configuration) [the deployment section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#deployment) of the reference manual for complete information about these properties.

However, you would not consume from the DLQ using a tap, but....

```
stream create errorStream --definition "rabbit ..."
```

i.e. use the `rabbit` source to pull from the DLQ.

Comment: I have configured DLQ  with ttl for retry errors I have created cycle with your help  so that retry errors and going back to stream.But system failures I want to write to  diffrent error  channel which may be  user defined rabbit queue.

Comment: You will need a more sophisticated environment; use DLQ TTL to route to a third queue; create a stream to consume from that and examine the `x-death` header to decide whether to route back to the original queue or give up and write to a fourth queue; consume from that to write to mongo.